# User lacks privilege or object not found.. with UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, prepared-statement, hsqldb

I'm trying this way to insert value in UPDATE statement. I'm getting an error:

> SQLSyntaxErrorException:User Lacks Privilage or object not found: intOne in statement.......

Code:

```
private int oneValue(){
 PreparedStatement ps= conn.prepareStatement("select col1 from 
  tableOne ");
  ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery;
  while(rs.next){
     String str=rs.getString("columnName").toString;
     int intOne= Integer.parseInt(str);
  }
return intOne;
}
Now :
private void theQuestionHere(int intOne){
 this.intOne=intOne;

 ps=conn.prepareStatement("update tableOne set col2=? where 
    col1=intOne);
 ps.setBytes(1,"anyByteArray");

 int anotherInt=ps.executeUpdate;
 if(int>0){
  System.out.println("OK");  
  }
 else{
  System.out.println("Not OK");  
  }
}
```

The use of intOne in the query string... can be or no?

If can, then why am I getting the exception?

Comment: `getString("columnName").toString` makes no sense (even if `toString()` was used correctly). If that column is a number, do not read it as a string, use `int intone = rs.getInt("columnname")` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `intOne` only exists in your java code. The database does not know what it is. You need to assign it the PreparedStatement.

```
private void theQuestionHere(int intOne){

byte[] aByteArray = byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
ps=conn.prepareStatement("update tableOne set col2=? where col1=?");
ps.setBytes(1,aByteArray);

ps.setInt(2, intOne);

int anotherInt=ps.executeUpdate;
if(int>0){
 System.out.println("OK");  
 }
 else{
 System.out.println("Not OK");  
 }
}
```